# Replace link in element with other elements link

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if its possible to switch a link between divs using jquery? I need to change the .mainPicture link to have the link of the a element. I started looking into replaceWith but got stucked. Whats the best way to do this?

HTML:

```
<a class="mainColorbox" href="/img/0~676B9DBB-5D93-4481-B241-74B619F96188~400~300~1"></a>

<div class="mainPicture">
    <img src="/imgs/7fb6d7bd-b9e7-44b2-a533-a485b93456ac/250/250" class="photo">
```

Update: I wasn't clear enough:

I want to replace the image link inside myelement ".mainPicture" with the link from the a element.

Comment: Check for jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). And `mainPicture` is not a link here. Clarify your question

Comment: To be more specific, do you want the div to have the href property from the anchor?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that you want to move that `a` element *inside* the `.mainPicture` div? Your question reads that you simply want to make the `div` clickable by adding the `href` attribute to it from the `a` - which won't work in itself.

Comment: So you got *stuck* - just the word *stuck* doesn't provide information on where exactly you were *stuck*, please provide us with a minimal sample of your JS code so that we can **see** what's wrong.

Comment: Or should the mainPicture show the image on the page?

Comment: Hang on, I just realised there was a missing line of HTML. I edited your question. Please take care to format correctly. It's still not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for this. Eg:

```
var href = jQuery(".mainColorbox").attr("href");

jQuery(".mainPicture img").attr("src", href);
```

Or simply

```
jQuery(".photo").attr("src", href);
```

Comment: To make sure that an element has a `href` attribute I would slightly modify your selector to make it specific to links with a href like: `a.mainColorbox[href]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link = $('.mainColorbox').attr('href');
    $('.mainPicture img').attr('src', link)
});
```

Check out the `.attr` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)